# Jarduino library not working

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, serial-communication, jarduino

I am writing a little arduino program that needs the arduino to be controlled from a java program on my computer. I want to use the Jarduino library (https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino/wiki/2-Minute-Tutorial) and have followed the install instructions, but when I try and upload the firmware to my arduino i get this error:

`exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'JArduino::init_JArduino()'`

How would I fix this, and if I cant, what is another way to easily control an arduino form a java program?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by modifying the c++ code
..\Arduino\libraries\JArduino\JArduino.cpp

Change the public method to:

```
// Public Methods
void JArduino::init_JArduino(void) {
    // init the serial port
    Serial.begin(9600);
}
```

And modify the template
..\Arduino\libraries\JArduino\JArduino.h

```
// Standard init and pool operations to be called in setup and loop
void init_JArduino();
```